# setTimeout/pausing/ etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a few different ways except the right one.

Trying this:

```
setTimeout( function() { 
    $('.historyTextBoxes p')
     .bind('showText', function(e) {
         $(this).fadeIn(800, function(){
             $(this).next().length && $(this).next().trigger("showText");
         });
    }).eq(0).trigger('showText');
}, 4000);
```

Will wait for 4 seconds, then fade each paragraph in, one after another at the speed of .800 miliseconds.

What I want to do is fade a paragraph in at .800 ms, then wait for 4 seconds before the next paragraph fades in.

The basic set-up of:

```
$('.historyTextBoxes p')
.bind('showText', function(e) {
    $(this).fadeIn(800, function(){
        $(this).next().length && $(this).next().trigger("showText");
        alert('pause here');
    });
}).eq(0).trigger('showText');
```

works but I've yet to hit the right syntax to make it pause where the alert is.

I tried throwing a call to a function but I don't need to run anything except just to wait.

So in pseudo code, I'm trying to define something like:

```
function wait() {
    pause(for 4 seconds);
}
```

Then I could just call that function instead of the alert above. My issues with `setTimeout` has been 'having' to define a function but I'm over thinking something.

Comment: you mean something like this? http://roxon.in/scripts/fademe_jquery_plugin/

Comment: pretty neat, but it seems to be cyclical. Good find though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` was correct, but you applied it in the wrong place.

```
$('.historyTextBoxes p').bind('showText',function(e) {
  $(this).fadeIn(800,function(){
    // this is the callback after the fadein
    // here we want to wait (use a timeout)
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length)
      setTimeout(function() {
        // before the next text is shown
        next.trigger("showText");
      }, 4000);
  })
}).eq(0).trigger('showText');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function showAll() {
    var p = $('.historyTextBoxes p').get();  // array of elements

    (function loop() {
        if (p.length) {
            var el = p.shift();
            $(el).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).promise().done(loop);
        }
    })();
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/4dNr3/2/

Note that this uses no explicit timers at all, and nor does it use any events to trigger the next phase - it relies on the animation queue for all timing.  Note that it's not *generally* a good idea to mix timers and animation unless you can guarantee that they're interleaved rather than running in parallel.   In this case that's OK, though.

Comment: I gave you an up because that's pretty darn cool. Hadn't seen this 'promise' before. Thanks for the input.